# "ERROR: role "$user" does not exist" when setting up postgresql server

Tags: 12.04, postgresql

When I tried to follow the "alternative server setup" as detailed here: [PostgresSQL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL), I got the error `ERROR:  role "$user" does not exist` when I ran `postgres=# \password $USER` and entered my new password. The instructions are very simple, and I followed everything to the letter. Would anyone know what's wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always best to copy/paste the command and error message so we might check your syntax.

Two thoughts - "$USER" is a variable, you replace it with the user name you wish to use. Also $user is not the same as $USER.

So ...

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser your_user
sudo -u postgres psql
```

You should not have a postgres prompt, again change "$USER" to the actual user name you wish to use ...

```
postgres=# \password your_user
```

and on ...

Comment: The instructions on Ubuntu's help page are confusing, since `$USER` works on the previous line when you're still in the general command prompt, but it doesn't once you enter `psql`.